# how to import the "django-sse" module?

Tags: python, django, module, server-sent-events

I want to import the module Django-SSE in one of my projects, but it errors because it has subtraction sign.

I've tried to import the library like this `import django-sse` and `import django_sse` and I've tried `from django_sse.views import BaseSseView` but none of theme worked.

so i'll be appreciate if you help me to import it and tell me is there any documentation about it?

Comment: Doing a web search results in https://github.com/niwinz/django-sse

Answer (score 0):

thanks of those who paied attention.
I should dwnload the sse pkage beside the djagno_sse and then

```py
from django_sse.views import BaseSseView
```

Comment: That's what it says to do in the link I posted in the comment.

Comment: yeah, I want to every one whom has this question know this.